# Expand ranges of numbers and output lines for each

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

So I have a data file with lines like this:

```
class subject
1-2   x
3     y
4-5   a
```

I need to extract the ranges given in the class column and print out the text in subject as many times as the ranges says so.
I should get something like this

```
class subject
1     x
2     x
3     y
4     a
5     a
```

Comment: I wanted to extract the ranges' numbers to two separate variables then substract them from each other. But I have trouble separating the value returned by awk. I need an other instance to do it?

Comment: Sorry, that is a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ if ( split($1, range,"-")>1 ){
           for(i=range[1]; i<=range[2]; i++) { print i, $2; };
           next;
       };
     }1' infile
```

`split()` the first column on `-` character and use first and second index as start and end of the range within loop and print the same line with incremental on range everytime, then read `next` line and do the same; if there was no range then output line with awk default print action `1`.

if there are other characters than dash for range, you can modify the third argument of the `split()` function to mention that too, like:

```
split($1, range, /-|,|\.\./)
```

to work on `-`, `,` and `..` as range characters.

sample input (Tab delimited):

```
class   subject
1,2     x
3       y
4-5     a
3..6    z
```

Output with modified `split()` to recognize `-`, `,` and `..` as range separators:

```
class  subject
1      x
2      x
3      y
4      a
5      a
3      z
4      z
5      z
6      z
```